# sbt fails to download components

Tags: scala, ubuntu, sbt

So I installed sbt on Ubuntu using the instructions at ., but when I execute `sbt` at the terminal, I get errors where downloads fail because "no trusted certificate was found". I'm not doing much, so I'm not sure what I could be doing wrong.

I have successfully downloaded one of these components (https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.13/jars/main.jar) using Google Chrome, and didn't notice it report any HTTPS cert errors.

This is a fresh install in Parallels of Ubuntu 16.04.

The full output is as follows:

```
parallels@ubuntu:~$ sbt
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.13 ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.13/jars/main.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/jars/compiler-interface.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.13/jars/actions.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.13/jars/main-settings.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.13/jars/io.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.13/jars/ivy.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.13/jars/command.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.13/jars/completion.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.13/jars/api.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.13/jars/collections.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.13/jars/incremental-compiler.jar ...
downloading https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.13/jars/compile.jar ...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.13!main.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (16019ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.13!main.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.13/jars/main.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/main/0.13.13/main-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.13/jars/main.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/main/0.13.13/jars/main.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (754ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/jars/compiler-interface.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/compiler-interface-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/jars/compiler-interface.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/compiler-interface/0.13.13/jars/compiler-interface.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.13!actions.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (763ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.13!actions.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.13/jars/actions.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/actions/0.13.13/actions-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.13/jars/actions.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/actions/0.13.13/jars/actions.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.13!main-settings.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (789ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.13!main-settings.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.13/jars/main-settings.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.13/main-settings-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.13/jars/main-settings.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/main-settings/0.13.13/jars/main-settings.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.13!io.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (766ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.13!io.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.13/jars/io.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/io/0.13.13/io-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.13/jars/io.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/io/0.13.13/jars/io.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.13!ivy.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (770ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.13!ivy.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.13/jars/ivy.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.13/ivy-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.13/jars/ivy.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/ivy/0.13.13/jars/ivy.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.13!command.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (712ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.13!command.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.13/jars/command.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/command/0.13.13/command-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.13/jars/command.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/command/0.13.13/jars/command.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.13!completion.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (705ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.13!completion.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.13/jars/completion.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/completion/0.13.13/completion-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.13/jars/completion.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/completion/0.13.13/jars/completion.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.13!api.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (769ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.13!api.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.13/jars/api.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/api/0.13.13/api-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.13/jars/api.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/api/0.13.13/jars/api.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.13!collections.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (703ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.13!collections.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.13/jars/collections.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/collections/0.13.13/collections-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.13/jars/collections.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/collections/0.13.13/jars/collections.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.13!incremental-compiler.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (721ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.13!incremental-compiler.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.13/jars/incremental-compiler.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.13/incremental-compiler-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.13/jars/incremental-compiler.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/incremental-compiler/0.13.13/jars/incremental-compiler.jar

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.13!compile.jar: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found (817ms)

        [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.13!compile.jar:  (0ms)

    ==== local: tried

      /home/parallels/.ivy2/local/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.13/jars/compile.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/compile/0.13.13/compile-0.13.13.jar

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.13/jars/compile.jar

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/compile/0.13.13/jars/compile.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::

        :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

        :: org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.13!main.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.13!actions.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.13!io.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.13!completion.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.13!collections.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.13!api.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.13!incremental-compiler.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.13!compile.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.13!ivy.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.13!main-settings.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.13!command.jar

        :: org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar

        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
download failed: org.scala-sbt#main;0.13.13!main.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#actions;0.13.13!actions.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#io;0.13.13!io.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#completion;0.13.13!completion.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#collections;0.13.13!collections.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#api;0.13.13!api.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#incremental-compiler;0.13.13!incremental-compiler.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#compile;0.13.13!compile.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#ivy;0.13.13!ivy.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.13!main-settings.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.13!command.jar
download failed: org.scala-sbt#compiler-interface;0.13.13!compiler-interface.jar
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/parallels/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.13
```

Answer (score 3):

After running into this issue installing sbt on Ubuntu myself I found the solution.  I believe we had the same error so this should fix it.  I have provided steps from beginning to end to download and install sbt on Ubuntu.  Start at step 4 if you just want to fix the error.

Type the following commands into the terminal.  Note that you can find these commands if you go to [www.scala-sbt.org/download.html](http://www.scala-sbt.org/download.html).

```
echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sbt
```

2) Now type `sbt` in the terminal, and it should install some .jar files and give you a REPL ('>' symbol).

2.1) If this worked, type `console` after the '>' sign and press enter

2.2) Now the prompt will read 'scala>'.  Type 3+3, then press enter just to test it out.

If you had errors after typing `sbt`, then continue on.  If you had no errors, congratulations!  You installed Scala and sbt!

3) If typing `sbt` in step 2 produced errors similar to the following picture then go to step 4.

[image: Picture of warning messages when running sbt]

4) You need to change the default JDK version to 8, as stated on the Stack Overflow answer here [Exception on download: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: No trusted certificate found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165525/exception-on-download-sun-security-validator-validatorexception-no-trusted-cer)

4.1) To do this type `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

4.2) Select the option with java-8 in the path.

NOTE: If you don't have an option with java-8 in the path, you should be able to download JDK8 and then go back to step 4.1 to set it as your default JDK.

[image: Screenshot of what options to select to switch to JDK 8]

5) Then run sbt again and it should work!

Comment: I needed Java 8